# Vkapi получение id фотографии

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
vk=vk_api.VkApi(token='ТИПО ТОКЕН')
vk.method(method='likes.add', values={'type':'photo','item_id':'?????'})
```

> вопрос в чём что писать за место вопросов допустим есть фото
>   https://vk.com/id163090987?z=photo163090987_373188783%2Falbum163090987_0

Для людей которые не понимают пайтон, я вызываю метод likes.add и что нужно передавать в item_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id Вашей фотографии - `373188783`

Чтобы получить id фотографий есть специальный метод [`photos.get`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.get?params[owner_id]=163090987&params[album_id]=profile&params[rev]=0&params[extended]=0&params[photo_sizes]=0&params[count]=20&params[v]=5.95)

Так же можно узнать id конкретной фотографии из URL. Он формируется следующим образом:
`<type><owner_id>_<media_id>`